# Import Error when import a python file to another

Tags: python, picamera

I am working on a project on a Raspberry Pi where I need to create a security camera system. I have 3 python files for this project one for live streaming, another one for motion detection and finally the last for activating the motion detection file from an android application. I am trying to make the live stream and motion detection file use the same camera. In the live stream file(**live.py**) I have imported a socketserver module to make the live stream, which works well when run. However, when I am trying to import the **live.py** file into the motion detection file(**motion.py**), I am getting an Import Error. The error is shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "motion.py", line 10, in <module>
      import live.py
 File "/home/pi/codes/live.py", line 7, in <module>
      import socketserver
 ImportError:No module named socketserver
```

I am very confused, I don't know what this error is. Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: did you pip install the dependencies?

Comment: Yes I have already install all dependencies required

Comment: You seem to be missing `socketserver`.

Comment: yes, but i have already imported socketserver in the live.py file. The problem is when am importing the live.py file in the motion.py file it gives this error. But when I run the live.py it runs fine.

Comment: When you important live.py it runs through the file once, therefore if live.py can’t run stand-alone it will not run when imported. If socketserver imports fine when you run the live.py seperate, there’s a convoluted issue with the importing that is hard to diagnose. Combine the files as a workaround if you can so they are in the same file scope.

Comment: Okay thank you I will give it a try

Comment: are any of these files in folders or subdirectories?

Comment: the files are subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

it looks like live.py is in a subdirectory. Python cannot access python files that are NOT in python packages. So, you need to ensure that all the folders that live.py is in are PYTHON PACKAGES.

To make a folder into a python package simply add a **init**.py file to each folder (you do not need to write any code in this file)

Then when you import live.py the import will look like this

```
from root.folder_name import live
```

Comment: okay thanks I'll try that.